# JPA use Map<ID, Entity> instead of List<Entity>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring JPA to design an e-commerce application. Suppose I have 2 classes `Product` and `Option` with one-to-many relationship, i.e. a `Product` will have many `Option` and an `Option` belongs to only one `Product`. With this, the typical JPA mapping would be

```
@Entity(name = "products")
class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private List<Option> options;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Please notice that the type of `options` is `List<Option>`. I am thinking of using `Map` instead of list here.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @MapKey(name = "optionId")
    @MapKeyClass(Long.class)
    private Map<Long, Option> options;
```

Using `Map`, I think it will be useful for updating and deletion options. For example, by using `List<Option>`, when I want to delete an `Option` from a `Product` given a option id, I would do

```
public void deleteOption(Long productId, Long optionId) {
    Product p = productRepository.findByProductId(productId);
    List<Option> options = p.getOptions();
    Option toBeRemoved = null;
    for (Option o : options) {
       if (o.getOptionId == optionId) {
          toBeRemoved = o;
       }
    }
    options.remove(toBeRemoved);
    productRepository.save(p);
}
```

But if I use `Map`, it will be easier.

```
public void deleteOption(Long productId, Long optionId) {
    Product p = productRepository.findByProductId(productId);
    p.getOptions.remove(optionId);
    productRepository.save(p);
}
```

### The Question

In general, is there a reason to use `List<Entity>` over `Map<Long, Entity>` for a one-to-many association? Can I always use `Map`?

Comment: I think you can use `List` and for delete option use `removeIf()` method. it's so easy to delete option.

Comment: You could maybe use a custom converter with the `@Convert` annotation, which creates a `Map` out of a `List`

Comment: First, you should use a Set rather than a List. Second, removeIf() is almost as easy to use as removing from a Map. But the most problematic part is that typically, when being created, an Option has no ID yet, and thus can't be stored in the map. Also note that the call to productRepository.save(p); is useless. JPA entities are managed (inside the transaction): any change you make to a managed entity is automatically made persistent.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks, I would like to accept your answer, could you repost it as an answer.

Comment: The real question is: would you model the association in the form of a map if it weren't for persistence? I doubt the `id` property, if present at all, would be that significant

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `List` and for delete option use `removeIf()` method. 
also it's better use `Set` to avoid duplicate option as @JB Nizet said.

```
p.getOptions().removeIf(option->option.getOptionId().equals(optionId));
```